# How to disambiguate between multiple associations between the same models in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, join, sequelize.js

I have three models — `Book`, `User` and `Institution` — which are associated to one another as follows:

- Books are associated to Institutions via a `Book_Institution` join table (many to many relationship)

  ```
  Book.belongsToMany(models.Institution, { through: 'Book_Institution' })
  ```

  and

  ```
  Institution.belongsToMany(models.Book, { through: 'Book_Institution' })
  ```
- Users can be associated to Institutions in two ways: as reader or author. This is done via two join tables: `Author_Institution` and `Reader_Institution`:

  ```
  Institution.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'Author_Institution' })
  Institution.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'Reader_Institution' })
  ```

  and

  ```
  User.belongsToMany(models.Institution, { through: 'Author_Institution' })
  User.belongsToMany(models.Institution, { through: 'Reader_Institution' })
  ```

  (Each time leaving out `foreignKey` for brevity.)

I want to query the `Book` model to find all books that belong to an author. Sequelize provides the `include` option to easily join two associated tables. The problem I’m stuggling with is that using `include` as shown below defaults to the `Reader_Institution` association. How can I specify which association should be used?

```
getBooks: (obj, args, context) => {
  const { user } = context

  return Book.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'path'],
    include: [{
      include: [{
        attributes: ['id'],
        model: User,
        where: { id: user }
      }],
      model: Institution,
      required: true // inner join
    }]
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `as` which allows you to reference the relationship through that alias.

```
Institution.belongsToMany(models.User, { 
    through: 'Author_Institution', // many-to-many relationship table name
    as: 'AuthorInstitution' // alias
})
```

With your models set up this way, you can use `as` to to specify which relationship you want to include when querying.

```
getBooks: (obj, args, context) => {
  const { user } = context

  return Book.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'path'],
    include: [{
      include: [{
        attributes: ['id'],
        model: User,
        where: { id: user },
        as: 'AuthorInstitution'
      }],
      model: Institution,
      required: true // inner join
    }]
  })
}
```

Also, with this methodology, it allows you you to reference the relationship data via the `as`, so you can do `book.AuthorInstitution` and it will be the value of that object.

Comment: Wouldn’t this result in a 1-to-many relationship instead of many-to-many?

Comment: Nope. I didn't change your structure, you would still have the belongsToMany on each object, I'm just changing the `through` to `as`. I'd venture a guess that you could leave the through and just add an `as` if you are more comfortable with that, but the `as` is essentially just creating an alias for the relationship.

Comment: `SequelizeAssociationError: belongsToMany must be given a through option, either a string or a model` — and including the `as` in the association definition doesn’t make it available in `include` (`"User is associated to Institution using an alias. You've included an alias (test), but it does not match the alias defined in your association."`,

Comment: I found some docs about the `through` option. It is the relationship table and required. I'm not able to test this at the moment, but did you try to leaving the through in there and just add the `as` to your association? Make sure you added the `as` to the association and the include.

Comment: Thanks! The alias strategy (using `as`) seemed to work. I was confused because the alias for `User` has to be set on `Institution`, so it took some time before I correctly implemented your answer.